# C++ Program loops forever

Tags: c++

I seem to be having an issue that I've been stuck on for hours. I run the program, and it just hangs after asking for the user input. My computer also begins to slow down unless I terminate the program. I have no idea what the problem is. I have tried commenting out code to see where the issue may be coming from. I put a cout statement after asking for the input, and even that does not display.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <array>
#include "problem2.h"

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int array[], int input);
void selectSort(int arr[], int n);

int problem2() {
    srand(time(0));         // generate seed based on current system time

    int rand[20];
    int result;
    int input = 1;


    cout << "Enter a number to search for: ";
    cin >> input;

    cout << "testset ";

    for (int z = 0; z < 19; z++) {
        rand[z] = random() % 70;
        cout << rand[15];
    }


    selectSort(rand, 20);


    for (int t = 0; t < 20; t++) {
        //cout << random1D[z];
        }
    result = binarySearch(rand, input);
    //cout << result;

    return 0;
    }

int binarySearch(int arr[], int a) {
    int high = 19;
    int middle =  19/2;
    int low = 0;

    while (arr[middle] != a && low<= high) {
        if (arr[middle] > a) {
            high = middle - 1;
        } else {
            low = middle - 1;
        }

        if (low > high) {

        }
    }
    return middle;
}

void selectSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int min, temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        min = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (arr[j] < arr[min])
                   min = j;
        }
        if (min != i) {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a well-formed program, there is no `main`.

Comment: You have a `while` loop that continues until you find a value in `binarySearch`, but you aren't guaranteed to find said value as you fill in your array with random values.

Comment: @R_Kapp is spot on.  This would have been evident had you tried to use a debugger. The cout doesn't display because the output is still in the output buffer.

Comment: If you want the testset to display flush the stream with `cout << "testset " << endl;`

Comment: Thanks R_Kapp, that seems to be the problem. I will try to figure out how to make it so the loop terminates if no value is found.

Comment: There is an error in sorting function. `low = middle - 1;` There must be +.

Comment: It doesn't stop, and if it had compilation errors it wouldn't run at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several loops, but all of them except for one have explicit termination. The `for` loops all end after a specific number of iterations, but your `while` loop is less certain. Your `low` is likely never going to be greater than your `high`, so the loop just keeps going.

Consider changing to `low = middle + 1` or altering your logic to more likely ensure that `low` will eventually overtake `high`. Or, change the condition the `while` loop checks.